# JS: Form Submit doesn't take added value

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

**Following Problem:** I need to place a value in an input field of a form, right before that form is submitted. I handle this with the jQuery submit() function. After hitting submit, the input value visually appears in the input field but when the form is sent there is no value set in my input field. And my validation handler says that field is required.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
HTML: 
<form id="form" method="POST">
   <input id="gps_daten" type="file">
   <input id="input" type="hidden">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


JS:
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form').submit(function(){
      input_file = document.getElementById('gps_daten').files[0];
      var data; 
      if(input_file){
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(input_file , "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = function (evt){
             data = evt.target.result;
             var geoJSON = toGeoJSON.gpx((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/xml'));
             document.getElementById('input').value = geoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0]);
          }
      }             
   }
   return true;
}
```

Somehow the form seems to be submitted while the FileReader is still working. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with a one time listener and a manual submit:

```
$('#form').one('submit', function(event) {
   ...
   $( "#form" ).submit(); 
   return false;
}
```

So the first time the form is not submitted and when manually calling submit, the submit does its default job.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

Change the element that you want to listen to. If I understand correctly you want the value of the hidden input field to be filled in with a value from the file input.

So in this case listen for the `change` event on the `#gps_daten` input. This event will be fired whenever the value of this input has been changed. In practice this will run your `FileReader` code whenever you upload a file to the input, before submitting the form.

Now when you would submit your form it will already have a value on the `#input` filled in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#gps_daten').on('change', function(event){
      var input_file = event.target.files[0];
      if(input_file){
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(input_file , "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = function (evt){
             var data = evt.target.result;
             var geoJSON = toGeoJSON.gpx((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/xml'));
             $('#input').val(geoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0]));
          }
      }             
   }
   return true;
}
```

## Original answer

Use the `event` parameter on the `submit` callback. This will open up the usage of the `Event` object that gives you information about your submission and some control over the event.

```
$('#form').submit(function(event){
  ...
```

At the end and inside the `submit` callback use `event.preventDefault()` to tell the browser not to execute the default behavior of the `submit` event. This will, like the name suggests, prevent the form from submitting.

```
  ...
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  return true;
}
```

Comment: If I get this right `event.preventDefault()` has the same effect like `return false; ` in the last line. It prevents the form from being submitted. But I do want my form to be submitted after the value of the hidden field is beeing inserted. How would I go on with this?

Comment: In this case you are right. When I have a simple FileField that would make it. However, I have a similar szenario where I need to solve the problem with the method I described. That the fields get filled right before the form is submitted..

Comment: Then using AJAX could be a viable solution to your scenario. Is that possible?